# Nested validation not updating on child VM change

Tags: c#, catel

I have a scenario with some nested model which I want to do validation on.

Since my UI is implementing drag and drop behavior with MVVM, and I don't want to put that logic in the model, there is a VM for some of my model classes.

For example `SiteConfiguration` has a VM named `SiteConfigurationViewModel`.

In such case, `SiteConfigurationViewModel` has a property of type `SiteConfiguration` that exposes the model.

The root VM contains a list of the top level VMs and the view (`DataWindow`) has some binding to show the list (`ListView`) of VMs instances  and a selected instance which the user can edit.

I am trying to implement validation but when I change the values in a nested VM/Model, the top window errors do not updated.

I tried many variations (e.g. validation annotations, overriding `ValidateFields` and `ValidateBusinessRules`, `ViewModelToModel` attribute) but I guess I am doing something wrong.

Comment: I added a property in the VM with ViewModelToModel attribute and now it is validating and updating the model - but once... if I enter a value and then reset it, new warning is NOT showing in the error list of the DataWindow. In addition, the OK button is not enabled/disabled according to the errors existence.

Answer (score 0):

If you only add errors to the model (and not the view model), the errors won't show up automatically. The reason for this is that Catel adds a WarningAndErrorValidator control for the view model for you, not for the model (because you might want to hide some validation). Note that the vm is fully responsible for the validation.

If you use ViewModelToModel mappings, Catel will automatically map all the validation for you as well (so you can validate on the model, map it on the vm and the vm will automatically expose all the mapped warnings / errors).

Comment: Hi Greet. This I manage to get working (with the ViewModelToModel) and it is working great. Still having the two issues described above - the OK button is valid when there are errors and after changing the value from a valid one to invalid one, I don't see warning (is this by design?)

Comment: There is an option for that on the VM. DeferValidationUntilFirstSave or something like that. Set it to false and you get validations immediately.

Comment: Still not working after setting DeferValidationUntilFirstSaveCall=false in all VMs.
What I do see is that I have an error with an `int?` bounded field:
System.Windows.Data Error: 7 : ConvertBack cannot convert value '' (type 'String'). BindingExpression:Path=NewBcfId; DataItem='BcfConfigurationViewModel' (HashCode=-1319402970); target element is 'TextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String') FormatException:'System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Could this stop the propagation of values/validation?

Comment: Yep, that was the issue the prevented the validation.
I added a `TargetNullValue` to the binding:
`<TextBox Text="{Binding MyProp, TargetNullValue={x:Static sys:String.Empty}}"/>` and now the validation occurs properly.
Still having validation errors won't disable the OK button (should having validation error disable it?)

Comment: There must be a reason for WPF to re-evaluate the canexecute state of a button. One way is to call this method yourself on child validation changes.

Comment: I am using a `DataWindow` as the base for the modal form I open (with `UIVisualizationService.ShowDialog`) - how can I explicitly call the `CanExecute` method of the OK button? Shouldn't changes in child VM do not "trigger" the CanExecute higher up the hierarchy?